# need to get the data from table 1 which is not present in table 2

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I need to find data which is present matching with data from some other table. 
Sample query I created is:

```
SELECT 
    a.TOTAL_TYPE, a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.CALLING_NUMBER, a.CALLED_NUMBER, a.C_NUMBER, a.CALL_DURATION, a.CALL_DATE_TIME, 
    a.USAGE_AMT, a.BATCH_NUMBER, a.PROCESSING_MONTH, a.BILL_CYCLE_START_DATE 
FROM 
    EMCESU.V_BIL_USAGE_EVENT_MAJOR a, EMCESU.TTY_ANALYSIS_PR2 c 
where
    c.account_id = '702297500' AND
    a.account_id = c.account_id and
    c.total_type = 344  AND
    a.total_type = c.total_type and 
    (substr(a.calling_number,2), substr(a.called_number,2), a.call_date_time, to_char(a.total_type)) 
       not in  (select 
                substr(b.s_p_number_address,4), substr(b.o_p_number_address,4), b.start_time_timestamp+(b.start_time_offset/86400), 
                to_char(b.TECHN_INFO_ETIS_total_TYPE) 
                    from EMCESU.RTX_TTY_COMPARISON_DROP5_PR2 b 
                    where cust_info_customer_id = c.CUSTOMER_ID and 
                          b.TECHN_INFO_ETIS_total_TYPE = '344')
;
```

Can someone please help me with some other better way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using NOT IN please prefer using NOT EXISTS to enhance the performance. As of now i have re-written the query but i am currently not having worksheet with me so there may be some syntactitical error but the logic remains same.

```
    SELECT a.TOTAL_TYPE,
      a.ACCOUNT_ID,
      a.CALLING_NUMBER,
      a.CALLED_NUMBER,
      a.C_NUMBER,
      a.CALL_DURATION,
      a.CALL_DATE_TIME,
      a.USAGE_AMT,
      a.BATCH_NUMBER,
      a.PROCESSING_MONTH,
      a.BILL_CYCLE_START_DATE
    FROM EMCESU.V_BIL_USAGE_EVENT_MAJOR a,
      EMCESU.TTY_ANALYSIS_PR2 c
    WHERE c.account_id = '702297500'
    AND a.account_id   = c.account_id
    AND c.total_type   = 344
    AND a.total_type   = c.total_type
    AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM EMCESU.RTX_TTY_COMPARISON_DROP5_PR2 b
      WHERE cust_info_customer_id                            = c.CUSTOMER_ID
      AND b.TECHN_INFO_ETIS_total_TYPE                       = '344'
      AND SUBSTR(b.s_p_number_address,4)                     = SUBSTR(a.calling_number,2)
      AND SUBSTR(b.o_p_number_address,4)                     = SUBSTR(a.called_number,2)
      AND b.start_time_timestamp+(b.start_time_offset/86400) = a.call_date_time
      AND TO_CHAR(b.TECHN_INFO_ETIS_total_TYPE)              = TO_CHAR(a.total_type)
      );
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS and NOT IN are not equivalent: they return different results.  Also it is not true that NOT EXISTS is always faster than NOT IN.  It depends on the data, its volume, distribution and skew.

Comment: Thanks APC for the explaination. So true

Comment: @APC Could you explain how `NOT EXISTS` is different from `NOT IN`? (might be an Oracle thing, I'm used to MSSQL and really can't think of a functional difference unless you want to be able to include `NULL` values in the mix somehow?). It seems that (in MSSQL) the optimizer is smart enough to see them as identical, but by experience I'd go for `NOT EXISTS` anyway, especially for readability reasons! Looking purely at performance I'd go for `EXCEPT` which *sometimes* comes out faster than the other two approaches, but it's often not as easy to incorporate depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways of finding records in one table which don't match records in another.

The first is the one you have, the NOT IN:

```
 select * from t1
 where t1.col1 not in ( select t2.col1 from t2);
```

The next is the subtly different NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from t1
where not exists ( select null from t2
                   where t1.col1 = t2.col1 );
```

These are two very different queries: NOT IN will return *zero rows* if any row in the result of the sub-query is NULL whereas NOT EXISTS will match the non-NULL records.

There is a variant on the above, the ANTI-JOIN:

```
select t1.* from t1
left outer join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
where t2.col1 is null;
```

Lastly there is the MINUS operation:

```
select t1.col1 from t1
minus
select t2.col1 from t2;
```

None of these is the "best" one: it really depends on knowing your data.  The ANTI JOIN is efficient when we know the sub-query will return zero rows.  NOT IN is efficient when the sub-query is guaranteed to contain no nulls.  The MINUS operator is efficient when we're just interested in the differentiating columns.  The NOT EXISTS is efficient when we suspect the sub-query may contain nulls.

Beyond that, it's like tuning any other query.  A lot depends on knowing the volume, distribution and skew of the data. How many records does the main query return?  How many records does the sub-query return?  We tend to assume that a sub-query returns a small set of records, and hence NOT EXISTS is the best choice.  But that may not be so. If the two result sets are of a similar size you may find the ANTI JOIN is a better choice.

So.  Use EXPLAIN PLAN to understand the choices the optimizer is making.  Understand your tables' indexes.  Make sure your statistics are accurate.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm).